# Is it possible to speed-up my Fortran code by parallelization?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I have a question about parallel computing. I don't much know about parallel computing, I just came up with an idea and I would like to discuss its practicality.

I am working on a Fortran code, and I have many do loops. For example:

```
do i=1,1000
    *some calculations
end do
```

The key point is inside the loop, I do some calculations such that the result of the current loop does not influence the next loop (i.e. calculations inside the loop are independent, I can obtain the result for `i=100` without having the result from `i=99`).

What I would like to have is instead of waiting single core to go over the whole loop, distribute this task (execution of do loop) between the cores and make it faster.

For such a scenario can I use parallel computing to increase the speed? I know there are some options in intel Fortran for optimization and parallel computing, but selecting these options is enough? Or do I need any additional code or subroutine to enable parallel computing?

Comment: Please make the question titles to somehow reveal the actual topic. Otherwise everyone could have titles like "A question about a Fortran code" that tells absolutely nothing. Also, you should probably show more actual code.

Comment: Please supply more details. Your description is *way* too broad. Many such codes can be parallelized, some cannot. The devil is often in the detail. I assume you are interested in shared memory parallelization (e.g., OpenMP). For start, try the automatic parallelization (`-parallel`). Report what happened.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF. I am a complete noob sorry for that. I have already opened the parallel option in VS (Fortran->Optimization->Parallelization-> Qparallel), but also saw some codes with the following statement at the beginning of do loops `!$OMP PARALLEL DO`.

Comment: Yes, those directives are OpenMP. You should read some tutorial first. We cannot teach you it in an answer here. We can answer questions about your specific code sampkes and parallelization efforts.

Comment: I am compiling the Fortran code to create a `.dll` file and put it into another software. I am not creating an executable so that I couldn't make a direct comparison of whether this parallelization (Qparallel) created a difference or not.

Comment: Try with standalone programs first. Move to advanced stuff later. Be aware that there can be incompatibilities in parallelization between the original software and your library. You must know what the original software does.

Comment: It also kind of depends on what memory is accessed by `*some calculations` and if it can be in the CPU cache or the greater RAM.

Comment: How long it takes now to do “*some calculations” is probably worthwhile to know.
Depending on whether you have 2 cores or 40, then comes into play.
Usually one finds an advantage to make the thing inside the loop more efficient, before they start to consider throwing more cores at the problem.